# The meaning of action's context in Interface ActionValidatorManager method validate

Tags: validation, struts2, struts, xwork

I wanted to use the following method for validation through XMLs on clientside.

Can someone please tell me about the context of an action as said in the following method:
Interface `ActionValidatorManager`:

```
void validate(Object object, String context) throws ValidationException
```

> Validates the given object using action and its context. 
> Parameters:
> object - ***the action to validate***.
> context - the action's context.
> Throws: ValidationException - if an error happens when validating the
> action.

I am not able to understand the meaning of action's context in this method.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Some client-side validations are already present.

Answer (score 1):

The action context is meant as validation context in terms of validation framework. The actual description

> The context that will be used by the
> [ActionValidatorManager](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/ActionValidatorManager.html) to associate the action invocation with
> the appropriate [ValidatorConfig](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/ValidatorConfig.html).
>
> The context returned is used in the pattern
> *ActionClass-context-validation.xml*
>
> The default context is the action name from the URL, but the method can
> be overridden to implement custom contexts.
>
> This can be useful in cases in which a single action and a single model
> require vastly different validation based on some condition.